# Creating GUIs in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am an experienced Java programmer and I now have the chance to learn C++. I've been through a few tutorials, but I haven't come to a GUI tutorial yet.

Are C++ GUI's created from scratch like in Java, using the swing library or its best to use drag and drop applications? Like C++ with Qt Designer. I know in Java its best to create GUI applications from scratch using swing and AWT and it is usually frowned upon to use GUI builder.

Comment: Check this out:- http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: @RahulTripathi thanks! that looks like a good tutorial. Quick question, it mentions win programs, would me using a mac or running on a mac affect this? Thanks.

Comment: Well all I can say is that C++ is platform dependent. And this Win32 API ;)

Comment: okie dokie, thanks agian! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ language by itself has no standard way to create GUIs. To do that, you need to choose a GUI toolkit. Some, like Qt or WxWidgets, are cross plaform, while other, such as MFC are tied to a particular OS.

Most GUI toolkits allow both options, either design the GUI from scratch, or use a graphical GUI builder and implement only the event handlers. It's up to you to choose the method you feel more comfortable with. Personally, I'm used to the Qt toolkit and the [Qt4 designer](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) interface designer.